# Changing the width of the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'd like to be able to change (in particular, make smaller) the width of my table of contents in the article document class without altering the margins of the page.  Is this possible??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "meta" answer to your question is that you can use the `tocloft` package to change the style of your ToC. (Or the memoir class, or KOMA-Script classes, etc.) But if you just want to change some margins, there's an easier approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{patchcmd}
\makeatletter
\patchcommand\@starttoc{\begin{quote}}{\end{quote}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{lipsum}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{lipsum}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{lipsum}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{lipsum}\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

The `quote` environment indents by, oh, `2.5em` I think. If you need a different amount consider using `changepage`’s  `adjustwidth` environment.